# Getting SSL error while trying to connect to SQL-Server 2014

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, tls1.2

Getting error while trying to connect to SQL Server 2014.
I'm using JRE7 and sqljdbc4-4.0.jar

here is my java code:

```
package com.test;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Testing {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test;encrypt=false";
    String user = "sa";
    String pass = "";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e);
    }
    
    try (Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user, pass);  
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM exts WHERE ext = 1001");){        

        if(rs.next()) {  
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT_FOUND");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}

}
```

Here is the full stack trace:

> java.ext.dirs: C:\Cisco\CallStudio\eclipse\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:dd9cabc2-3683-4a14-857c-eeefd2751853".
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
> at com.test.Testing.main(Testing.java:32)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:dd9cabc2-3683-4a14-857c-eeefd2751853
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:651)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:708)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:700)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:895)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:883)
> at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
> at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
> ... 7 more

Comment: Microsoft stopped [supporting sqljdbc4-4.0.jar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix) back in 2017. You really should upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: any suggestions, cause i'm using jre7

Comment: same result @AbhinabaChakraborty

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty I can't enable Force Encryption because SQL Server is getting used by some other programs as well.

Comment: Can you disable it and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL exceptions occur when TLS version mismatch. As you are using Java 7, Try to add sslProtocol=TLSv1.2 to your connection string.